# How to transfer data from one server to another server

Tags: php, rest, webserver

I am having some data in **Server A** i need to request the **Server A** using some api to get the data, after fetching the data from server A i need to refine that JSON Response which i got from Server A, and i need to send that refined JSON data to **Server B**

[image]

**Note : I don't do any UI work just i need to run the code to transfer data**
But I do know which language or framework should i use to implement this, and where to start this.
Can anyone suggest me ?

Comment: What have you tried so far in order to achieve this?

Comment: @Johannes i am new to server side.

Comment: You should at least try it before asking us...
Your goal is to write a script fetching data from Server A, transforming and passing it to Server B (like a proxy)? Are there APIs available you can call on server A and B?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the data from **Server A** you can use [PHP cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php). Transform the output to the desired structure, for example by using `json_decode()`, transform and then `json_encode()` to pass it to **Server B** using another PHP cURL call.

```
// receive from ServerA
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://SERVER_A_URL");         
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);         
$serverA = curl_exec($ch);         
curl_close($ch);  

$serverA = json_decode($serverA); 

// some transformation
$serverB = [
    'varOne' => $serverA->varOne,
    'varTwo' => $serverA->varTwo
    // ...
];

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://SERVER_B_URL");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($serverB));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);      
$serverA = curl_exec($ch);         
curl_close($ch);
```